# about tor selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Hello guys I try to use tor in C# I find some sources on the website but I have some problems
please help me :

```
        WebDriverWait Wait;
        IWebDriver Driver;
        String torBinaryPath = @"D:\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe";
        Process TorProcess = new Process();

        TorProcess.StartInfo.FileName = torBinaryPath;
        TorProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-n";
        TorProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
        TorProcess.Start();

        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
        profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
        profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.Profile = profile;
        Driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        Wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://whatismyipaddress.com/");
```

the problem is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWi70.png)

Comment: Because new FirefoxDriver(); wants an option, not a profile

Comment: how can i give profile to option

Comment: You need to create option, instead of profile

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an option and not a profile.
Please check the example below.

```
FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
opt.Profile = new FirefoxProfile();
opt.Profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
opt.Profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
opt.Profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);
this.Driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
```